# ag-grid colDef appears inconsistent between events

Tags: angular, ag-grid

according to [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/) ag-grid column definitions can be used to update cell css class. colDef object is available in column events, i.e. newValueHandler and cellValueChanged. I am trying to use this to add/remove css classes.

It works in **newValueHandler** but does not work in **onCellValueChanged**. I can see both of these events args expose a colDef object, but the following works only in newValueHandler:

```
dropdownValueUpdateHandler(p, key) {
        this.svc.updateProductField(p.data.ID, p.colDef.field, p.newValue.code)
            .catch(err => {
                p.colDef.cellClass = 'ag-etp-cell-failed'; // <---- updating cell to show error
```

the last line works in first event, but on cell value changed event it does nothing.

**update: attempting to use dynamic function but that's not working correctly either (or im doing it wrong)**

```
getCellClass(p){
    console.debug('getCellClass ', p);
    return p.data.Status == 'saved'
        ? 'ag-etp-cell-saved'
        : p.data.Status == 'failed'
            ? 'ag-etp-cell-failed'
            : '';

}
```

in my valueUpdatedHanler on success:

```
e.data.Status = 'saved';
e.api.refreshCells([ e.node] , [e.colDef.field]); // this has a weird lag, doesn't refresh correct, doesn't seem to call getCellClass function
e.api.refreshView(); // this works but refreshes the whole grid which can be costly
```

the updates sort of work, but subsequent events seem to lag behind, i.e. if previous event was a fail, the next success still comes back as fail style

if i refresh the whole grid, it works. but i was hoping to avoid doing that since it's a big grid..

Comment: which version of ag-grid are you using btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the column definition, You have to tell ag-grid to refresh to pick up the changes. You can do it by calling `gridAPI.refreshView()` to refresh the entire grid or `gridAPI.refreshCells(rowNodes, colIds)` to just refresh that cell.

CellClass will just add classes to the cell without removing previously added.

You may want to use cellClassRules to handle more complex rule

```
cellClassRules : {
    'ag-etp-cell-failed': function(params) { return params.data.Status === 'failed' },
//etc
},
```

Comment: hey thanks ! ok so for some reason in newValueHandler it just works without refreshing. if i do call refreshView from cellValueUpdate, it actually applies this style to all rows :( is there a way to apply the style only to a single row?

Comment: trying to go the refreshCells route, but its not clear how to supply nodes and cell ids from that event.. documentation doesn't really say much more than what you did :(

Comment: trying to do it like this: e.api.refreshCells([ e.node] , [e.colDef.field]); with no luck so far

Comment: it should work. i tested it in my app `api.refreshCells([p.node], [p.colDef.field])`

Comment: You may need to rethink about your approach though, changing the cellClass will change the css to all rows in that column, so if you want to use this approach to update an individual cell, you will need to disable the auto refresh in the grid down the line. FYI, sorting, filter will trigger refresh. IMO, this is more problematic than using context.

Comment: is there nothing in the api to change one cell style?

Comment: cell class can be a function, but you will still need some kind of indicator.

Comment: ok that could work. If i add a .Status property to my underlying object, could i base style on that? values ('', 'saved', 'failed') etc

Comment: trying this, but it's not working right. updated my question with details :(

Comment: as crazy as it sounds, when you inspect the cell, do you see both 'ag-etp-cell-saved'and 'ag-etp-cell-failed' there?

Comment: actually yes! that's exactly what happened. any ideas why?

Comment: cellClass will just add classes to the cell without removing previously added. you could set the ag-etp-cell-saved css take precedent than ag-etp-cell-failed though. Or you can try with cellClassRules (which i haven't tested)

Comment: guess i'll submit it as a bug

Comment: yea, refreshView() is like redrawing the entire grid (ie, destroying the dom and recreate them, hence removing all the previously added css classes) while refreshCells does not. You may want to try with refreshRows(), it may work but not as expansive as refreshView()